# Jquery find() doesnt work in IE but it works in google chrome.

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have the following code - 
  $.map(find(********code *****)) 
This particular code gives error in IE that 'find' is undefined. It works fine in google chrome.

what could be the solution for this?

Comment: in the find functionality the attribute of a control is set. nothing else. While debugging the Js , i am not able to step over the find functionality in IE and it says 'find' is undefined. It is able to step over in Google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code as follows:

```
if (typeof window.find == "undefined")
{
    window.find = function(str){
        return document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML.indexOf(str) > -1;
    }
}
```

Put above code at very beginning , may be in `<head>` and then after your following code should work:

```
 $.map(find(********code *****))
```

Comment: Hi. Now after adding your code - i get the following error - Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference. i am using mvc and razor engine. This code is added to a Js file.

Comment: can you please add `debugger` inside this newly added `window.find()` function and check what you get for `document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML`

Comment: can you please try one more thing: simply copy `document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML` and run it in console. See what you get? Also check what you get for `$("body").text()`

Comment: for - $("body").text() it is showing some result. For document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHtml it is still showing 'undefined'

Comment: ok...so assuming you will have jQuery always with you on your page you can replace `document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML` with `$("body").text()` within that `window.find = function(str)`. I hope that will work.

Comment: yours solution now removes the previous error. But now i receive error like - 'Function ' expected from the Jquery file - jquery-1.7.2.min.js'. Do u have any ideas about this./

Comment: Actually the code is like this - $.map(find($(selector ***code***), function() {
                                    find($(selector + ***code****')).attr('***code****', "0");. Hope this gives u better idea

Comment: can I know what exactly your trying to do.. Can its possible for you to explain it with simple example. I am not able to visualize the output of above line of code.

Comment: My code is like this -  $.map(find($(selector + ' {class name}')), function() { find($(selector + ' {class name}')).attr('{attribute name}', "0"); });. So its quite clear i am looping through the elements and setting the attribute. If you are still not sure, could u let me what was your logic behind using the code - if(typeof window.find......... that would be helpful for me to get the solution myself. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.